# Index of ta.lowest

Tags: pine-script

Pretty straightforward, I am trying to get the index of ta.lowest, not the value

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "xxx", shorttitle = "xxx", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="")
src = input(close, title="Source")
l_val = ta.lowest(src, 14)
```

This returns the lowest price within the range, but I want the index of that value within the range. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lowestbars()` which returns the lowest value offset for a given number of bars back.

Note: It will return a negative offset, so you might probably want to change its sign before using it as a value with the `[]` history-referencing operator.

Comment: Thx. This works ``l_val = ta.lowest(src, 14); l_inx = ((l_val - 1)/-1) -1``